# How do you handle $f(x)$ when inside an integration?

Tags: integration

I'd like to integrate the following, which contains a function. I'm not sure which rule I need to review? I thought maybe I could bring it out of the integral - but not sure what it would become?
$$\int^n_1\frac{f(u)}{u^{1+p}}du \Rightarrow f(?)\cdot\int^n_1\frac{1}{u^{1+p}}du \Rightarrow \bigg[\frac{u^{-1+p+1}}{-1-p+1}\bigg]^n_1\Rightarrow \bigg[-\frac{n^{-p}}{p}+\frac{1}{p}\bigg]$$

Comment: You can't do that. If it's an unknown function, you can't find its integral, unless in special cases. What's the double arrow is supposed to mean here?

Comment: You can't take the function out of the integral because it is dependent on $u$... Where did you find this integral? Could you provide some context? The way it is, we cannot make sense of it as we don't even know if it continuous on that interval...

Answer (score 3):

If it's just an arbitrary function, then you unfortunately cannot separate it outside of the integral. To spell it out, if $f(u) = u$, then clearly $\int f(u) du\neq u \int du = u \cdot (u+c) = u^2 + uc$ for a constant c, since the correct answer would instead be $\frac{u^2}{2} + c$. You can expect this incongruency with most if not all choices of f(u).

Comment: linus is that you haha

Comment: @HenryLee $lttstore.com$

Answer (score 3):

In general, you have the [Mean value theorems for definite integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_definite_integrals). It says that

> if $f : [a, b] → \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $g$ is an integrable function that does not change sign on $[a, b]$, then there exists $c$ in $(a, b)$ such that
> $$
> {\displaystyle \int _{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)\,dx=f(c)\int _{a}^{b}g(x)\,dx.}
> $$

But this theorem only tells you the *existence* of $c$; there is no "algorithm" that tells you what $c$ is.